# Hot to turn a Plaid created Stripe ACH bank account token (btok) to payment method?

Tags: stripe-payments, plaid

I was following the Stripe ACH guide (https://stripe.com/docs/ach) to create a bank account token (btok) with Plaid. Now having this btok I am wondering how to use it as a payment method to pay an invoice with it. I did that with credit cards previously without problems and am using them now in connected accounts, so the goal is to achieve the same with ACH.
I don't see ACH as a payment method type here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PaymentMethods API doesn't support ACH payments at this time (but it's coming soon):

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods#supported-payment-methods

That being said, you can still use a customer's saved bank account to pay an invoice. The approach would be start by saving the token to the customer, as shown in the first code snippet in this section:

https://stripe.com/docs/ach#manually-collecting-and-verifying-bank-accounts

Once the bank account is saved/attached to a Customer you can create an invoice item on the Customer and invoice the Customer for those invoice items:

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/sending#one-off

Comment: See @habib answer's it is now possible to create stripe source with a plaid source token

Answer (score 2):

just craete stripe customer and craete a bank account using that plaid_stripe_token you have:

(using PHP sdk)

```
$stripe->customers->createSource(
            $customer->id,
            ['source' => $stripe_token]
        );
```

**These bank accounts are payment methods on Customer objects.**

Reference: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_bank_accounts

Comment: Awesome! This should be the current working answer as 2023